# R Lazy Evaluation- not working

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I played with Advanced R examples http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html
and got different results. According to the book, R lazy evaluation is the default. But for me, it seems like it's been turned off. Why is that and how to resolve it?

What I got:

```
add <- function(x) {
    function(y) x+y
}
adders <- lapply(1:10, add)
adders[[1]](10)
[1] 11    **The book gave 20 instead of 11**
adders[[10]](10)
[1] 20
```

Comment: The first element in `adders` is a function that adds the number `1` to its argument (it's the result of calling `add(1)`). So `adders[[1]](10)` is like calling `add(1)(10)` which correctly gives 11. Try `get('x', envir=environment(adders[[1]]))` to see what is "x" in the environment of `adders[[1]]` (it will be 1) , `get('x', envir=environment(adders[[2]]))` and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R 3.2.0 this change was made to R:

> Higher order functions such as the apply functions and Reduce() now
>   force arguments to the functions they apply in order to eliminate
>   undesirable interactions between lazy evaluation and variable capture
>   in closures. This resolves PR#16093.

This can be found in the R 3.2.0 section of:

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html

Also see:

https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16093

### Demonstration using pre-3.2.0 version of R

Adding `force` to the code in the question will cause pre-3.2.0 R to work the same as 3.2.0.

Using R 3.1.3 we can show the difference by using `force` and not using `force`:

```
R.version.string
## [1] "R version 3.1.3 Patched (2015-03-16 r68169)"

# adding force to the code in the question
# In R 3.2.0 onwards conceptually R acts as if this R 3.1.3 code were run
add <- function(x) {
    force(x)  # <---------------------------
    function(y) x+y
}
adders <- lapply(1:10, add)
adders[[1]](10)
## [1] 11

# not using force, i.e. using identical code as in the question
add <- function(x) {
    function(y) x+y
}
adders <- lapply(1:10, add)
adders[[1]](10)
## [1] 20
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!! And sorry, I just took off rm command

Comment: In the `force` example: does it really produce 10 or should it be 11?

Comment: Have fixed. It produces 11.